# Converting dates to date time objects in pandas while maintaining the original formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of dates that take the format: YYYY-MM. They are currently stored as objects, and I wish to convert them to a date format so I can subtract two dates from each other to calculate the number of months between two dates.

When I run:

```
df['cohort']=pd.to_datetime(df['cohort'])
```

The format goes from YYYY-MM to YYYY-MM-DD... How can I maintain the same formatting while converting them to date objects?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input example and the matching expected output? When you say `object` do you mean that you have strings?

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't: Just create a new value for total months

Going to date objects will create a whole new world of woe for you. You are so lucky that you already have *exactly* the information you need (year and month) and nothing more to confuse you (day and time). Don't lose that!

Don't lose the info you already have. Create a new column which is a simple numerical month count, that you can just subtract as a number.

For example, convert `1985-07` to 1985*12 + (7-1) = 23826.

And `1986-03` to 1986*12 + (3-1) = 23834.

The difference in those numbers is 8, and that is the time difference in months.

#### Example code

```
yyyymm1 = "2021-03"
yyyymm2 = "2022-09"

def toMonths(yyyymm):
    return 12*int(yyyymm[:4]) + (int(yyyymm[5:]) -1)

months1 = toMonths(yyyymm1)
months2 = toMonths(yyyymm2)

monthsBetween = months2-months1
print(monthsBetween)
```

Result = 18

Answer (score 0):

By using infer_datetime_format=True, it will automatically detect the format and convert the mentioned column to DateTime.

```
df['cohort']=pd.to_datetime(df['cohort'])
df['cohort'] =pd.to_datetime(df['cohort'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```